# List of my own publication

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

How do I include my own list of publication in report?

This is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
% whatever you need here, basically a good idea is to use your real thesis header
\begin{document}
$ " $ Vacuum Linear Feed Through Drive using Stepper Motor and Lead Screw$ " $ by Kusum Soneji, NUiCONE 2013 ,4th Nirma University International Conference on Engineering.
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{myrefbibfile}
\end{document}
```

and then I am generating `.bbl` file for it.
in main file how to call it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you specify your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having trouble in compiling a latex file with bibliography using natbib. IF this is the real issue, then please note the following:

1) With your current MWE example, please keep the file `myrefbibfile.bib` in the same folder as your manuscript `.tex` file

2) To compile, follow this sequence: Run latex, the run bibtex and then run latex twice. So its: latex bibtex latex latex.

You do not need to worry about the .bbl file that is created during the compilation process (except understanding various specific issues that you may face with due experience, regarding formatting and ordering the bibliography entries).